# Make str.index() match only whole words

Tags: javascript, regex, indexing

I want to match whole words using the JS function "index()"

I want to return **-1** on this:

```
var str="hello I am a string";

alert(str.index("str")); //it matches because of STRing, but don't want
```

**Edit:** But I strictly want to match "str" only when it appears sorounded by two spaces (but also matching when it is at the beginning/end of a sentence). So `\b` don't work for me because I do NOT want to allow `"hello I am str. how are you?"`to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
(^|\s)str(\s|$)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the word you want to search for and put `(^|\s)` on one side, which means either the beginning of the string or a whitespace character, and `($|\s)` on the right side, which means the end of the string or a whitespace character:

```
var str = "hello I am a string";

alert(str.search(/(^|\s)str($|\s)/)); // alerts -1
alert(str.search(/(^|\s)string($|\s)/)); // alerts 12
```

Comment: well, I noticed that the word break makes "str-ing" "str.ing" matchable. I strictly want to match only "str" if it sorounded by 2 spaces (but also matching when they are at first/last of a sentence)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
alert(str.search("(^|\\s|\\W\\s)str($|\\W$|\\s|\\W\\s)"));
```

This matches "str" as a word on its own at the start, end, or somewhere in the middle of a string. Punctuation before or after "str" must either be followed by either at least one white space character or the end of the string. That way, "str" can start or end a sentence ("a str. ing") but "str.ing" won't match.

Comment: I really want to match only words sorounded by white spaces and beginning/end of sentences

Comment: OK, gotcha.Before I edit my answer to accommodate this restriction, would you want a match on something like "something str:" or only if the final punctuation between "str" and the end of the string is a period?

Comment: your ans is quite original and might help someone else. I think it would be best if you leave it as it is. Others already answered what I want, so changing your ans to the same others will do nothing but erase an interesting answer :)

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the "search" methods above, I've also seen adding spaces for this exact test. I've seen it in testing whether an element has a certain class.

```
var str = "hello I am a string"

(" " + str + " ").index(" str ");
```

Your index will be off by one, but if you're going for existence (and not position), this will work.

Comment: `" " + str + " "` won't match first/last elements

Comment: Also won't count cases with punctuation like `str,`

Comment: @AbhranilDas, well I actually want that to happen, see my question edit

Comment: @TuxedoKnightChess Right, I missed the spaces around "str" for some reason. By adding spaces to the front and back of the string to check, and to what you're looking for, you will catch the first or last word.